# Suppose that for every sequence $s_n$ in A, the limit of $s_n$ is in A. Show that A must be closed.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$.

**Suppose that for every sequence $s_n$ in A, the limit of $s_n$ is in A. Show that A must be closed.**

My Attempt:

*Let $s_n$ be a sequence in A and $s=lim(s_n)$. We know that if $s_n,s\in A$ and $s_n \to s $ then s is a cluster point of A. We also know that since every $s \in A$, then A contains all it cluster points, thus implying A is closed.*

Is this correct?

Comment: Is $A$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime yes

Comment: For me,this is the definition of closed set. How do you define closed sets?

Comment: @cello - the sequence definition of closure only works in spaces that are first countable (every point has a countable basis of neighborhoods). In spaces such as the closed long line, it fails to behave as desired. The general definition is that a set is closed if its compliment is open.

Answer (score 1):

That is not adequate. You've shown (actually, you've just stated, but I assume this has already been covered in your course) that

$$(s = \lim s_n \text{ with } \{s_n\} \subseteq A) \implies (s\text{ is a cluster point of }A)$$

But your conclusion requires 
$$(s\text{ is a cluster point of }A)\implies (s = \lim s_n \text{ with } \{s_n\} \subseteq A)$$

Until you've proven that implication, your proof is incomplete.